# how to handle an exception in change password?

Tags: swift, amazon-cognito

Function which change password in my app:

```
@IBAction func changePassword(_ sender: Any) {

    let isMatched = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", regexAllValidation).evaluate(with: newPasswordField.text)
    if (isMatched == true){
        let auth = Auth()
        auth.changePassword(oldPassword: oldPasswordField.text!,newPassword: newPasswordField.text!)
        displayAlert(title: "Correct password", message: "Password changed!")
    }
}
```

Class Auth:

```
func changePassword(oldPassword: String, newPassword: String){

    let user = 
        AppDelegate.defaultUserPool().currentUser()?.changePassword(oldPassword, proposedPassword: newPassword)
            AppDelegate.defaultUserPool().currentUser()?.clearSession()
}
```

When I call this function with bad old password, I receive in console:

```
Response body:
{"__type":"NotAuthorizedException","message":"Incorrect username or password."}

"x-amzn-errormessage" = "Incorrect username or password.";
    "x-amzn-errortype" = "NotAuthorizedException:";
```

I would like to display an alert informing the user of a wrong password.
how do it?

Comment: this function `AppDelegate.defaultUserPool().currentUser()?.changePassword` must have a closure, normally its call it `completion`, its have it?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which framework you are using, but if you are using swift and cognito, then I recommend the amplify framework, more specifically AWSMobileClient.

It is filled with common functionalities and heavily documented with common scenario like what you mentioned.

Link: https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/sdk/ios/authentication

In short, you should have completion closure where you could handle the different scenarios and display alert if needed. For example, using AWSMobileClient you can

```swift
AWSMobileClient.default().confirmForgotPassword(username: "my_username", newPassword: "MyNewPassword123!!", confirmationCode: "ConfirmationCode") { (forgotPasswordResult, error) in
    if let forgotPasswordResult = forgotPasswordResult {
        switch(forgotPasswordResult.forgotPasswordState) {
        case .done:
            print("Password changed successfully")
        default:
            print("Error: Could not change password.")
        }
    } else if let error = error {
        print("Error occurred: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```